# Firestore Rules coverage report - Request expression never evaluated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Recently I have been using firebase for my new app. Since you can define your own rules on firestore, I wanted to try that out.

To test these rules I am running the firestore emulator. When I try to authorize some test user I always get a timeout error. Wanting to solve the error by myself I've made some research.

I have found out that it is possible to see the "Firestore Rule Coverage Report" and inside there I've seen this:

[image: Error message of Firestore Rule Coverage Report]

But since I am new to firestore I did not know what this is and also after some googling I didn't find out how to solve this problem.

Comment: It's some months old now. Did you succeed?  Have you updated the firebase-tools ? The rule looks solid to me.

Comment: Same problem here. All my rules work fine (I even deployed them and everything is ok) , but the report says that none of my rules are evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore docs are a bit confusing. They state that the  URL should be:

`http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/<database_name>:ruleCoverage.html`

However, they don't explain what `<database_name>` should be replaced with your `project_id`.  *Yes... reading the URL some might thing is obvious, but is really the argument name that should make it obvious. Plus, in Firestore databases are not created neither accessed by name.*

**SOLUTION:**

`<database_name>` should be replaced by your `project_id` (this value is available in the files `.firebaserc` or `google-services.json`

So, if your `project_id` is `my-amazing-app`, your rulesCoverage url would be: 
`http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/my-amazing-app:ruleCoverage.html`

Comment: This is not the OP's problem. They could already reach the report page.

Comment: In fact the report page is shown even if using the wrong URL, and it will correctly display the rules, however, they will appear as "Expression never evaluated" when hovering.

Comment: @Rohit, **please remove the unuseful flag to prevent visitors from discarding this correct answer**. I spent a significant amount of time debugging this issue before reaching the conclusion exposed in my answer. The very reason it was time consuming is the same reason you intuitively discarded this answer - I assumed that if I was seeing the rules then the URL wouldnt' be the problem, to then learn the hard way that the assumption was in fact incorrect.

Comment: I tested your solution and it didn't work. Here is a screenshot showing both my .firebaserc file and browser window. I would be happy to upvote your answer if you can tell me what I got wrong. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1divxB_dmnhn06lOUZaUCJPSHxgwvLjsN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please try what happens if instead of using your project name (video-veda) in the URL, you use any other random lowercase string (i.e. http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/random:ruleCoverage.html)? You will see the same page report, however no rules will show up as evaluated. For my specific case, when I changed the URL to use the right project name, it started working. **Please keep in mind, a working solution might fix some specific casuistics, whilst other casuistics might require different solutions**.

Comment: I still can't figure out my problem but any I will respect your effort and remove the down vote and let the OP decide for himself.

Comment: @Rohit Maybe my answer is helping you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369467/8358501

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I executed `loadFirestoreRules` before every test. I changed it to run `loadFirestoreRules` only one time for all tests, and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the examples from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing . Bu two examples for security rules, only the example for version 8 at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing/tree/master/unit-test-security-rules is working. Although I am using JS SDK v9, but using the example for version 8 can help me testing my security rules just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the root of the problem is that the expression is throwing an error. If the user isn't authenticated then request.auth will be null (and therefore request.auth.uid will throw a null reference error).